# Django: Using simple-history module I get auth_historicaluser doesn't exist error

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-admin

I'm using django 1.8 in windows 7 and I use `django-simple-history` module and it works properly.

Looking my tables in mysql on windows I have both `auth_historicaluser` and `auth_historicalgroup`.

Today I moved my project to ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I install all the `installed_apps`.

When I'm trying to create a superuser or access `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` my project raised an error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/

(1146, "Table 'cy_thal.auth_historicaluser' doesn't exist")

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'cy_thal.auth_historicaluser' doesn't exist")
```

In `admin.py` I have:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from simple_history import register

register(User,inherit=True)
register(Group, inherit=True)
```

Comment: Have you run the migrations?

Comment: Yes, this is what I run: 'manage.py migrate auth' and `manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to run this actions as `sudo`:

```
sudo python manage.py makemigrations app
sudo python manage.py syncdb
sudo python manage.py migrate auth
sudo python manage.py migrate
sudo python manage.py runserver
```